# Cypress response.body binary SHA256 differs when using CryptoJS

Tags: cypress, cryptojs

I have the following Cypress + CryptoJS code which works perfectly, except for the sha256 hash. It finds the URL link, downloads the ~30k PDF file, and saves it locally. The end goal is to have the test verify the response bytes against a known hash, not save it to a file.

- The length of the response.body is identical to the server file and the saved file.
- The `sha256sum` of the server file and the saved file is identical.
- ***The SHA256 of the response.bytes, however, is different.***

Am I using Cypress and CryptoJS properly to send the exact bytes of the PDF to the `CryptoJS.SHA256` function?

```
  cy.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pdf')]/a").invoke('attr', 'href').then(href => {
    cy.request({
      url: href,
      encoding: 'binary',
    })
    .then((response) => {
      cy.writeFile('/Users/jc/document.pdf', response.body, 'binary');
      console.log('length: ', response.body.length);
      console.log('SHA256: ', CryptoJS.SHA256(response.body).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
    })        
  });
```